# laravel: eloquent example insert data to database

Tags: model, insert, laravel, primary-key, eloquent

I am sorry to ask this but I come from codeIgniter and have a really hard time understanding eloquent model insertion. This is a new way of working with models for me.

i have read [this article](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships) and understand some basics now.

I have the following example. I have a product which has many attributes but the relevant one is brand and product name. (see the following example tables)

products: id(PK),name,description,brand_id
brands: id(PK),name

Now here comes the problem. I know i can create a new brand and I know how I can create a new product. However I have no qlue how to connect the two together. Here is some code I have right now. I want to create a new product and automatically fill the brand table. This is a part of the controller right now.

In short. I want the brands.id inside the products.brand_id

```
    $product = new Products;
    $product->name = "product1";
    $product->description = "description1";

    $brand = new Brands;
    $brand->name = "brand1"
    $product->brand()->associate($brand);

    $brand->save(); 
    $product->save();
```

To make it more clear. I have 2 models. products and brands models. However it is not clear to me what should be in the model. This is my Current products model. I think the brands model only should have a protected $table = "brands"; line inside the model class.

```
 class Products extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function brand()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('brands');
    }
  }
```

Can somebody explain to me what i do wrong. I cannot find a good tutorial how to work with inserting data inside eloquent models with relationships. The most tutorials are about displaying data.

Comment: You may need to save the brand before even calling `$product->associate();` Have a go at that.

Comment: Just noticed in your post you say that you "think the brands model only should have a `protected $table = "brands";` line", but that's not true as far as I know. I'm pretty sure that model must have a `public function product() { return $this->belongsTo('Product'); }` method, that way the call to `associate()` on the $products model can fill in the `product_id` field on the `Brands` model. I'm not 100% with a `hasOne`, but that's definitely how it is with a `hasMany`, and it's the same kind of thing in the inverse of the relation (i.e. the model has a `foreign_id` column).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Okay, I've re-read your question and I think you have a few things wrong, so rather than leaving any further comments on the main post I figured I could have a go at an answer, so here goes.

First off, your relationship is the wrong type and the wrong way around. As I understand it (and as I implement these things in my own work) a product belongs to a brand - a brand may have multiple products, but a product can only have one brand. So first your DB schema - you mention you have a `products` table with the normal columns and then the foreign key `brand_id`. So far so good: this is consistent with the way I interpret the relationship.

However, you then go on to show us your model. You have the Product model as `hasOne` Brand - but actually it belongs to a brand. You also don't define the inverse of the relationship - you need both sides to make Laravel work well. In addition to that your naming is a bit out of whack - it'll possibly work, but if we follow Laravel conventions we get the following:

In the `products` model: `Product.php`

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Brand');
    }
}
```

Now the `brands` model: `Brand.php`

```
class Brand extends Eloquent
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Okay so far so good. You'll notice various conventions:

1. Table names are plural (`products`, `brands`)
2. Foreign keys use the singular (`brand_id`)
3. Model names are singular and StudlyCase (so `Product` for a table `products`, `Brand` for table `brands`)
4. The `$table` property doesn't have to be specified as long as you follow Laravel conventions (i.e. table name is the plural snake_case version of the model classname
5. You should define the relationship both ways (one in each model, `belongsTo`'s inverse is `hasMany`, there's also the pairs `hasOne`/`belongsTo` and `belongsToMany`/`belongsToMany`)
6. The names of the methods to retrieve the relationship are sensible - if you expect one result, make it singular (`brand` in `Product`), if you expect multiple results make it plural (`products` in `Brand`)
7. Use the model classnames in your relationship definitions (`$this->hasMany('Brand')` not `$this->hasMany('brands')` or any other variation

If you stick to these rules, your models can be really concise but very powerful.

Now, as for how you actually define real data, I have a feeling the code you posted may work fine (it really depends on how clever Laravel is behind the scenes), but as I suggested in my first comment, I'd ensure that I saved the `$brand` before calling `associate()`, just so that Laravel doesn't get lost working out what to do. As such I'd go for:

```
// create new brand and save it
$brand = new Brand;
$brand->name = "Brand 1";
$brand->save();

// create new product and save it
$product = new Product;
$product->name = "Product 1";
$product->description = "Description 1";
$product->brand()->associate($brand);
$product->save();
```

This way, you know you have the brand in the database with its IDs already defined before you go and use it in a relationship.

You can also define the relationship in the opposite manner, and it may be less brain-hurting to do so:

```
// create new product and save it
$product = new Product;
$product->name = "Product 1";
$product->description = "Description 1";
$product->save();

// create new brand and save it
$brand = new Brand;
$brand->name = "Brand 1";
$brand->save();

// now add the product to the brand's list of products it owns
$brand->products()->save($product);
```

You don't need to call `save()` on either model after that last line, as it wil automatically take the `$brand`'s `id` value, place it into the `$product`'s `brand_id` field, and then save the `$product`.

For more information see the docs on how to do this relationship inserting: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many

Anyway, hopefully this post clears up a good amount of what was wrong with your code. As I said above, these are conventions, and you can go against them, but to do so you have to start putting extra code in, and it can be quite unreadable for other developers. I say if you pick a given framework, you may as well follow its conventions.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but how come? I thought my answer was pretty well thought-out and answers the question as well as suggests improvements to the original code (as it was a little messy, and may not even have worked as it was). Very happy to hear criticism.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. It worked and also important: I got a clear example of the naming convention. Thnx

Comment: No problem at all. Free free to upvote too to undo the work of whoever downvoted it if you want to.

Comment: @alexrussell This is a great answer but I need your help something related to this. I have inserted `new Brand` and now I have to insert multiple products related to the inserted brand. What will be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Tiger I would imagine that, assuming what you're saying is that you have a `Brand` that already exists and need to add various `Product`s that don't yet exist, you should be able to use `$brand->products()->createMany([])` (see [here for Laravel's implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L337)). However, if your issue is not as simple as this, I would suggest opening a new question about it.

Comment: @alexrussell thank you so much for your response. Actually, I was looking for the many-many relationship with the pivot table. I got very good example [here](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/) that helps me to get it done. Might be it can help others too :)