# Laravel push a one-to-one relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, push, relation

I have a one-to-one relation for my products and their corresponding prices. What I would like to do, is when I create a new product, the new product is stored in the "products" table, but that also the price is saved in the "prices" table, including the "products_id". Here is what I have now:

Products Model:

```
class Products extends Eloquent {

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Prices');
    } 
}
```

Prices Model:

```
class Prices extends Eloquent {

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Products');
    }
}
```

Controller Store Method:

```
$product = new Products;
$product->name = Input::get('name');

$product->prices->price = Input::get('price');

$product->push();
```

I am getting an error though:

Indirect modification of overloaded property Products::$prices has no effect

dd of my $product:

```
object(Products)#606 (20) {
    ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) {
       [0]=> string(4) "name"
       [1]=> string(8) "selected"
       [2]=> string(6) "number"
    }
    ["connection":protected]=> NULL 
    ["table":protected]=> NULL
    ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id"
    ["perPage":protected]=> int(15)
    ["incrementing"]=> bool(true)
    ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) 
    ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["original":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) {
       [0]=> string(1) "*"
    }
    ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["with":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL
    ["exists"]=> bool(false)
}
```

Comment: can you show me the dd of your $product?

Comment: Added in my answer since it was too long for the comment :)

Comment: Sorry sir. Please use this code:  $product = Products::all(); then use print_r($products). And show me the data's tnx.

Comment: Edited in my question again.

Comment: Does `$product->prices->price = Input::get('price');` creates a new price model and saves it to the database? Check your database if it's really created.

Comment: Nope, prices is empty

Comment: Could it be a naming issue? Eloquent expects your models class names to be singular. So `Price` instead of `Prices`, and `Product` instead of `Products`, while the database tables should be plural.

Comment: Probably there is an issue with that and I have no clue as to why I am using "Products" for my model instead of "Product". So I'll start there :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push is can be used when updating data and its relations but you have to first save product then save price when creating first time.

```
    $product = new Products();
    $product->name = 'pro2';
    $product->save();

    $price=new Prices();
    $price->price=3;


    $product->prices()->save($price);
```

Also you should use transaction for data to be in consistent state.

Comment: You could use `$product->price()->associate($price);` And then do a single `$product->save()` at the end.

Comment: yes it could be also instead of new Product() ,Product::create can be used to remove save statement

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now using the right naming conventions and with this code:

```
        $product        = new Product;
        $product->name      = Input::get('product');
        $product->category_id   = Input::get('category');
        $product->save();

        $price          = new Price;
        $price->price       = Input::get('price');
        $price->save();

        $product->price()->save($price);
```

Answer found here:

[laravel: eloquent example insert data to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814049/laravel-eloquent-example-insert-data-to-database)